# How can I check until a time si enabled in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have a new category with name `"Black Friday"`.This category has a custom design which is valid from the date of `17.08.2016 to 20.08.2016`

I want to check until is enabled this theme for my category

I tried something like:

**CODE PHP:**

```
<?php
    $specificCatID = '16';
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($specificCatID);
    if ($category->getIsActive()) { //here have changed condition
        echo "test";
    }else{
        echo "test2";
    }
?>
```

You please tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me get this right... `You want to check if for your category is enabled between those dates`... or `You want to check if its enabled only` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment yet, so i will do it like this.
Do you mean that you want echo something between these dates ? and something else outside these dates ? like something like this:

```
if(date('Y-m-d') >= '2016-08-17' && date('Y-m-d') <= '2016-08-20')
{
    echo 'Yes its between 17-08-2016 and 20-08-2016, or is one of these dates';
}
else
{
    echo "Whoops, its not 17-08-2016 yet, or 20-08-2016 has been expired";
}
```

If not try to be a little more clear in your question..